# Facebook login pop up using C# and javascript or javascript alone

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

**Use Case:** I want to create a login button for "Login with Facebook". I want this functionality to be implemented using c# or asp.net with JavaScript or with JavaScript alone.

**Requirements:**

**1)** On the click of "Login with Facebook" button a pop up asking for email address should be visible.

**2)** When the user enter(s) the email address then a verification email is sent to the user.

**3)** When the user clicks on the "Verify" button in the email, then the user gets redirected to the Home page.

**4)** On the home page a pop appears asking user to provide permission to access the facebook details.

**5)** When the user finally allows it, it gets login from his facebook account.

Can anyone provide me a explanation for the above task? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? Not OAuth2?

Comment: In the OAuth2 authentication sequence there is no email address required from the user. This is the whole point. So logging in with Facebook starts with a button click.

Comment: 1) StackOverflow cannot provide the project solution, so you have to design & develop each requirement yourself.  Hence 1st code, then if struck anywhere, post a specific question.    2) Check FB Connect to allow its authentication to be used in your app.

Comment: @Adelin this question is a _very_ poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use OAuth2 and follow the recommended process by facebook. Have a look at the documentation of the facebook graph API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api).

Remember to create a facebook developer account [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

If youre using ASP.NET, there is an included Facebook OAuth2 client. Have a look at this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on). Its actually pretty easy to accomplish a simple facebook login and retrieve an access-token.

I know thats alot of links but you will have to first read a bit about the whole process to understand how it works.

Hope this helps and good luck.